# How to get the Date Format and Time Format settings for use in my template?

Tags: customization, options

This is a strange question, but I want to know how I can access the Date and Time settings

```
Admin > Settings > General > Date Format
Admin > Settings > General > Time Format
```

I am using the [Any+Time jQuery plugin](http://www.ama3.com/anytime) as a date/time selector for the editor view for a custom post type.  It allows you to specify a date and time format <strike>using the same settings WordPress does</strike>. **Edit: Turns out it doesn't use the same Date part tokens that WordPress does. Lame.**

http://www.ama3.com/anytime/#AnyTime.Converter.format

Ideally I want to do something like this...

```
<?php 
  $wpDateFormat = get_admin_settings('DateFormat');
  // $wpDateFormat now holds something like "F j, Y"
?>

<script>
    $("#datetime").AnyTime_picker({
      format: '<?php echo $wpDateFormat ?>'
    );
</script>
```

What I don't know is... is there such a function like `get_admin_settings()` ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
get_option('date_format');
get_option('time_format');
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out that the jQuery plugin uses different date and time tokens to specify format after all. So, while this doesn't solve my problem at hand, I appreciate you sharing for my future benefit.

Comment: very nice, thanks a lot... didnt knew i could do that :)

Answer (score 15):

You want get_option(). In particular:

```
$date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
$time_format = get_option( 'time_format' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a small PHP function that maps the WordPress format specifiers to the Any+Time™ specifiers?  Then you can accomplish your goal :)

Comment: Someone has already written [a conversion from php `date()` to `strftime()` format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#96424), and I think [the MySQL format Any+Time uses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is compatible with the latter.